# How to send multiple values having same key in Axios as params

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have requirement where I want to select multiple categories and subcategories and send their ids as a query string using Axios. Let's suppose if user has selected 2 categories having ids 1 and 2 and from these two categories he has selected subcategories having ids 31 and 65, I want request URL to be like this :

https://example.com/api/data?categories=1,2&subCategories=31,65

How can I achieve this desired format of URL?

Answer (score 0):

Here you try this logic : (**steps**) :

1. **npm i axios**

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function Api() {
  const response = await axios.get("https://example.com/api/data", 
  { params: { categories: '1,2' , subCategories : '31,65'} })

  //receive data from request
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
}

Api()
```

Comment: My question is how can i append these category and subcategoies in a url as I have provided.

Comment: here you can append : axios.get("https://example.com/api/data", 
  { params: { categories: '1,2' , subCategories : '31,65'} })

Comment: its a default way of axios that i have provided you